# Shortest path over multiple 2D points

Tags: python, graph-theory, path-finding

Is there some clear algorithm to build shortest single path over multiple (50-100) 2D points? My code now only creates all possible pairs of points and sorts them by distance between them (also finds some path but the result is wrong anyway), that's where I've stopped. I guess it's called travelling salesman problem, still don't know how it solves.

- Path may start in any point (additionally would be good to have
  algorithm that requires starting point).
- Edges can cross each other in any way.
- Path may be looped.
- Each point must be visited just once.

Input example:

```
data = \
{
    'use826' : (2847.8216, -2684.7392),
    'use828' : (3084.755, -2405.0912),
    'use830' : (3076.3209, -2601.099),
    'use832' : (2640.6552, -3276.4813),
    'use825' : (4203.8915, -2631.0695),
    'use827' : (3488.6186, -1911.4069),
    'use829' : (3967.5091, -2306.3344),
    'use831' : (4608.4849, -2543.0039),
    'use833' : (3738.085, -2558.4143),
    'use835' : (4587.6737, -2103.5679),
    'use837' : (3853.6183, -2031.5337),
    'use839' : (3922.8349, -1902.1021),
    'use841' : (4009.2469, -2900.3685),
    'use843' : (4494.0819, -1561.8019),
    'use845' : (3979.8622, -1666.955),
    'use847' : (3794.5993, -1432.1888),
    'use849' : (4720.4179, -1664.6266),
    'use851' : (3778.1488, -2993.7347),
    'use853' : (3206.4287, -2821.2921),
    'use855' : (2998.8622, -2017.08),
    'use857' : (2633.3272, -1940.517),
    'use859' : (3050.3445, -1724.1992),
    'use861' : (4382.4229, -1330.3753),
    'use863' : (3162.013, -942.60612),
    'use865' : (4377.4605, -789.03192),
    'use867' : (4823.0815, -3493.3768),
    'use869' : (1770.0685, -3489.3226),
    'use871' : (1838.671, -3141.7945),
    'use846' : (3495.526, -5519.6035),
    'use848' : (3967.7469, -4777.4685),
    'use850' : (2802.4209, -6180.7663),
    'use852' : (2326.2043, -4984.3239),
    'use854' : (3352.2024, -6437.9083),
    'use856' : (3653.2145, -4427.3605),
    'use858' : (5781.6893, -6258.1416),
    'use860' : (4435.9003, -5095.2394),
    'use862' : (5061.0899, -6975.1303),
    'use864' : (3114.1242, -4537.4805),
    'use866' : (3896.3969, -5194.2308),
    'use868' : (4323.8934, -4406.9115),
    'use870' : (5653.7428, -5036.3394),
    'use872' : (4321.7852, -5511.5559),
    'use874' : (5626.0947, -5603.8763),
    'use876' : (6271.3207, -5762.3393),
    'use878' : (4967.0411, -5993.336),
    'use880' : (4958.347, -5118.1762),
    'use882' : (5240.4535, -5901.5248),
    'use888' : (5534.7647, -2947.2948),
    'use890' : (3656.9612, -6853.8227),
    'use892' : (3562.2834, -3552.0658),
    'use894' : (5386.1129, -4446.1217),
    'use896' : (3910.0082, -7113.1804),
    'use898' : (5157.5199, -4759.4803),
    'use900' : (3572.0501, -3141.5484)
}
```

Comment: Could you please input some sample input and expected output to the question?

Comment: @arsho I've added input example. Output can have any form (sorted list, image, etc.).

Comment: Not an answer, but https://github.com/jvkersch/pyconcorde may be useful in the future.

Comment: this is a standard problem in programing(Traveling Salesman), it is NP-Hard ... there is no short cut other than full evaluation, any greedy approach will fail under circumstances... with certain rules you can come up with better algorithm's, however in general you must totally explore the search space

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia page. Using general purpose methods, your example can be solved, but no problem much bigger. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem